# Problem with managing my *ngFor for array object

Tags: html, angular, angular8, ngfor

My object is:

```
 {
    "name": "OCA Netflix",
    "workflowNames": [
      "OCA-Netflix-Action",
      "OCA-Netflix-Action-v2"
    ]
  }
```

When I use ngFor in my html i use:

{{ usecase.workflowNames }}  and I see elements separated by ",".

How can i insert in my code to see elements in a column?

**EXAMPLE:**

Not: `OCA-Netflix-Action, OCA-Netflix-Action-v2`

But:

```
OCA-Netflix-Action
OCA-Netflix Action-v2
```

Comment: make a nested ngFor for your array

Comment: Can u share the code u tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*ngFor directive](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor) with [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) and add `br` tag to provide a new line.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let v of usecase.workflowNames; let l = last;">
  {{v}}<br *ngIf="!l"/>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Use below code in html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of usecase.workflowNames;let i=index;">
    <div>
        {{item}}<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---